# How to remove Chromeos_pstore module that is loading on Ubuntu

Tags: boot, kernel, 22.10, chromeos

a few weeks ago, I did a Live Boot of ChromeOS Flex on my Ubuntu 22.10 Laptop just for the sake of checkin' it out but decided not to install it but now whenever I boot Ubuntu and press 'esc' or left arrow key to see the list of modules loading, I see that a module called 'chromeos_pstore' is also loading. How do I delete it since I know that it isn't an integral part of my OS.

Comment: `systemctl disable --now modprobe@chromeos_pstore` will do the job most likely

Answer (score 1):

You can black list the module by going into /etc/modprobe.d and either putting the module into blacklist.conf or by creating a new .conf file with the module name in it.

blacklist chromeos_pstore

However when I searched my ubuntu 22.04 I was unable to actually find the module loaded with a lsmod even though the boot shows it being loaded. I think it just tries to load it in case you have that type of hardware.